# Only show X and minimize button on wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, button, minimize

I don’t want the user to resize the window so I did `ResizeMode="NoResize"`. But then the minimize button also disappears and only the `X` button is visible. Is there a way to keep the minimize button?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[WPF Windows Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx). `ResizeMode="CanMinimize"`